# How can we ensure that text doesn't fall down when neighbor text wraps to multiple lines

Tags: html, css

Please check the problem statement in the plnkr below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ojt3l3ljNYOA6HDq

```css
.d {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  >div {
    display: inline
  }
}

.a {
  float: left;
}

.c {
  float: right;
  top: 0;
  position: relative
}

.b {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>How do we get c to take top-right position!</h1>
<div class="d">
  <span class="a">a</span>
  <span class="b">basdsadjkasdl ksaalsdk jsald kjsaldkajsdlaks</span>
  <span class="c">c </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forget about the float's, use flexbox, and set the `d` as `display: flex`

```css
.d {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">
  <span class="a">a</span>
  <span class="b">basdsadjkasdl ksaalsdk jsald kjsaldkajsdlaks</span>
  <span class="c">c </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. Another way to go about it is using absolute positioning on a,c and put d as relative position.